# ng-repeat is not showing anything

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is my code and ng-repeat generated the list but not showing anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>


</head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">

    <div ng-controller="getHospitalCtrl">

        <h3>my list</h3>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="hospital in hospitals track by $index">
                    <p class="name">{{hospital.name}}</p>
                    <p class="location">{{hospital.address.city}}</p>
                </li>               
            </ul>
        </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
        app.controller('getHospitalCtrl',function($scope, $http){

        console.log('i m in getHospitalCtrl');

        $http.get("url")
        .then(function(response){
            $scope.hospitals = JSON.stringify(response.data.data);
            console.log($scope.hospitals);
             //this console is printing the right json here
    });

});
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The json in console is like this

[{"_id":"57a5877bb23cda352156315a","userId":257,"name":"Fortis","email":"fortis@hospital.com","description":"Fortis description for testing","address":{"postalCode":"110088","state":"DL","city":"New Delhi","streetAddress":"s-fortis"},"coordinate":{"coordinates":[77.1545846,28.7164134],"type":"Point"}}]

Comment: your json array is same as console.log(response.data)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your code:

First you have

```
$scope.hospitals = response.data;
```

which initializes $scope.hospitals to what is returned in the http response.

But immediately after you have

```
$scope.hospitals = JSON.stringify($scope.hospitals.data);
```

So you're overwriting this value with **a string**. Using `ng-repeat` on a string doesn't make sense. `ng-repeat` is used to iterate over an **array**.

You should just have one initialization:

```
$scope.hospitals = response.data.data;
```